# Can non-web applications use OpenID?

Tags: wpf, openid, dotnetopenauth

How can I make my desktop application into an OpenID relying party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OpenID has a specified protocol, it will either work all the time (assuming providers are conforming) or not at all. Additionally, since the OpenID protocol (at least the authentication bits, see [the specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html)) consists of simple HTTP requests, you could implement the protocol in a desktop application assuming you know how to make such requests.

It is generally considered a bad idea though, since there are better technologies (OAuth) and it disrupts the user experience (being different from OpenID in a browser — see [OpenID For Desktop Applications: How? When?](http://iiw.idcommons.net/OpenID_For_Desktop_Applications%3a_How%3F_When%3F)).

Further reading: [OpenID for Desktop Clients](http://blog.wachob.com/2007/03/openid_for_desk.html)

Comment: Linden's OpenID + OAuth solution discussed at IIW8 conference sounds like it would work. But it sure isn't simple.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386973/web-service-authentication-using-openid), it looks to me that [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) can do this for you.

Comment: I considered OAuth too, but it misses the point of using the existing OpenID ecosystem for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should present a small web browser window for the authentication to be completed.  The interaction would not be going through your code.

I would not suggest using web scrapers to do this.  In doing so, you place your code in between the user's server and the user, which is a breach of the covenant that the user's password is not seen by the relying party.

OAuth is the right *technology* to use for a desktop application, but it doesn't use the existing password ecosystem that OpenID has, which was not a part of the OP's question.

Comment: You're right. I don't want to have to see the passwords at all. That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do it**.

Even an attempt to do so shows a fundamental lack of understanding in the security model that OpenID offers.  You have to ask yourself what the password that you would otherwise use for your desktop app is protecting.  Is it protecting assets on the local machine itself?  If so, OpenID is useless because it would be a simple matter to spoof the network such that I could hack my way into the desktop app without owning the OpenID.  You're wide open to user identify spoofing.  Are you trying to protect network assets?  OpenID fails again, since it doesn't authorize your desktop app to access those network assets, suggesting that some other authentication is going on behind OpenID so once again you're not adding any value.

OAuth is the protocol suited to allow your desktop app to access and protect network resources.  If you're protecting local assets on the desktop computer, local encryption is the only way to go.