# Is there a way to implement OpenAuth outside of the browser without resorting to hacks?

Tags: windows, oauth

I would like to implement OpenAuth in a Windows application. I am currently embedding a browser inside the application, but this solution sucks.

Is there a way to do this using raw APIs?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can do it by firing off https requests from whatever language you choose.  I had something working that used oauth to connect to facebook written in pure php.

Comment: Yeah, possibly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386973/web-service-authentication-using-openid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634408/can-non-web-applications-use-openid

Comment: I am kinda looking for a solution where I can be lazy and not re-invent the wheel though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention a browser, I assume you are interested in implementing an OAuth client, not a provider.  You can try the [Scribe library](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java).  It's written in Java, has client implementations for several different providers and is pretty easy to extend for new providers.