# What's the benefit of OAuth for securing REST APIs?

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication, oauth

I want to make a web application that's a Single-Page client that interacts with a REST API in the server. I need to authenticate users of my app as opposed to authenticate third party-apps (the latter being the focus of most tradional REST bibliography).

After googling a lot, I found there are many options (Basic HTTP Auth, HTTP digest, OAuth, etc) and several desirable properties one might get depending on the one chosen. For example, Basic Auth is simple but sends plain passwords unencrypted, which is not a good idea unless you guarantee that your app will run under TLS. Digest on the contrary doesn't send the credentials on every request, but prevents strong password encryption and is vulnerable to man in the middle attacks[[1]](http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2013/how-to-authenticate-apis-http-basic-vs-http-digest/). Meteor introduced SRP which avoids storing and sending passwords[[2]](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2012/10/17/meteor-050-authentication-user-accounts-new-screencast).

It appears to me that the consensus is to use OAuth, particulary the OAuth2 credentials flow, since I want to authorize access to my resources on my own server[[3]](http://tatiyants.com/using-oauth-to-protect-internal-rest-api/)[[4]](http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf)[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386973/web-service-authentication-using-openid). What I don't get is what are the benefits of this particular approach. I do get the benefits of using OAuth as a form of delegate authentication, much like those of using OpenID for federated authentication: you don't handle authentication data at all in your server. But in the case you apply the credentials flow for authorization (or OAuth1 2-legged flow for that matter), not introducing a third party, it looks like you still have to handle authentication by some other means, like HTTP basic or digest. So if you're doing that why not stick to that only method, and send the credentials on every request, instead of the token?

It's just to reduce the amount of requests where you have to actually send the credentials? It's just to stick to the OAuth convention? Those don't sound like strong arguments over the other methods. So, I'm I missing some other aspects or did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not federating, there is not really a good case for using OAuth.

If you just want to authenticate to your own service, basic or forms authentication is the way to go. The catch, as you've pointed out, is that you must use HTTPS.  However, that applies to all authentication methods.

As long as you're using HTTPS, you can leave protection of credentials while in transit to the transport level security. That's what it's there for and (for the most part) that's what it's good at.  If you're using plain HTTP (anywhere in your application, not just for authentication), you're done.  There are all manner of very clever MitM attacks that totally break the security of any system that employs HTTP anywhere (Moxie Marlinspike gave an interesting presentation on the subject at Black Hat back in 2009).

Comment: Do you have a link to that presentation?

Comment: I thought Basic of HTTPS isn't as good as token based authentication because first, you need to send password everytime, and could be an issue if someone breaks the CA signing key and start signing a new cert that matches yours.  (unless you do pinning).  Also bandwidth is an issue if always sending user/p every time.  I can be wrong, please do say so if I'm.

Comment: If someone stole your CA's signing key, you're totally screwed period.

There are of course some problems with Basic Auth, that's why I also mentioned forms auth (which is probably a better solution in most cases).  I don't like the way most browsers cache Basic Auth credentials and the differences in the way they handle UTF-8 passwords are staggering.

That's a reason why I mentioned forms auth.  Unless you need to support basic auth for API reasons, forms is probably a better way to go.